# Max value in array, based on a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects. I want to find the "maximum" of this array based on a function that returns whichever object is bigger when given 2 objects.

```
function comparison(first, second) {
    // ... arbitrary comparison based on properties...
    return first; // or second
}

var a = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var maxObj = ????(comparison);
```

What do I fill in here? What's elegant and short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be quicker than sort (depending on the data):

```
/*
  values: array of values to test.
      fn: function that takes two arguements and returns true if the first is bigger.
*/
var maximum = function(values, fn) {
    var currentValue, maxValue = values.pop();
    while(values.length)
        maxValue = fn(maxValue, currentValue = values.pop()) ? maxValue : currentValue;
    return maxValue;
}
```

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/SaBJ4/2/

Even better, use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var a = ['abc', 'defg', 'highlkasd', 'ac', 'asdh'];
a.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b; }); // highlkasd
```

Comment: The downside is that that function modifies its input, that may or may not be a problem.

Comment: +1 for `reduce` but you'll need to special-case empty arrays and arrays with only one element (depending on the behavior of `comparison`), using an explicit initial value can help.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the obvious approach?

```
for(var i = 0, max; i < a.length; ++i)
    max = typeof max == 'undefined' ? a[i] : comparison(a[i], max);
```

Wrap that up however you like.

---

Or you can take advantage of the fact that `a = []; x = a[0]` leaves you with `undefined` in `x` and do it RobG's way:

```
for(var i = 1, max = a[0]; i < a.length; ++i)
    max = comparison(a[i], max);
```

That nicely avoids a bunch of `typeof` operators and comparisons that you really don't need.

Comment: Why not initialise `max` as `a[0]` and `i` as `1` and avoid the ternary expression?

Comment: @mu *blush* Of course you're right; that doesn't apply at all to this case. Deleting my silly comment.

Comment: @RobG: That's a great idea and even behaves properly when the array is empty, I guess I still have old habits from C.

Answer (score 0):

```
[obj,obj,obj].sort(comparison)

// aka
var sorted = [obj,obj,obj].sort(function(a,b){
  // return 1/0/-1
});
```

Then either pop the top or bottom element off (however you're sorting) to get the "max" object.

[Array.Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: This is effective, but inefficient; finding the max should be O(n) while this is O(n^2) (worse case).